# generate mulitple text boxes depending on drop down menu selection

Tags: javascript, html, button

I want to have a drop down menu that selects either rgb or hsl  or the hex # code for the specific color they want, and a submit button that once the user selects their option and pushes submit, 3 text boxes appear for either the rgb or hsl option, or 1 text box for the hex#code to allow them to input the correct # for it to correlate to the color option they want. in the end, this assignment will display the color they chose to input, but for now, i just want to get the drop down menu and text bars working. how should I go about doing this? ive been trying to write code for it and I cant seem to get it.

to summarize ==> select option:  |rgb, hsl, hex| ==> user pics one, and clicks submit. depending on if he choose rgb/hsl or hex, 3 input text boxes will appear or 1 box will appear. along with the boxes appearing will also appear another button called generate. so they can submit their input to display the color.

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far.

Comment: At least do the HTML for how you want the elements to appear and add that to your question. Fatih has kindly implemented something for you, though if you're a beginner I'd recommend doing this sort of thing without jQuery so that you get a better understanding of what's actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following code snippet to learn something about logic and usage of jQuery then please don't post any question like this anymore, try on it then try again, if you still can't get it, paste your code and learn what you're doing wrong.
More motivate to do something. Good luck.

[Check the Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Vc9jX/1/)